# Is it possible to load angular 4 module using compiled chunk.js JavaScript file?

Tags: angular

I want to know is it possible to load or import  angular modules in the form of compiled JavaScript (someModule.chunk.js)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? practically no.

Comment: I have a tons of widgets which i want to load specified  widgets dynamic module for particular user... I don’t want to store all modules (widget) in local

Comment: Maybe, if you can do without the .chunk requirement. More generally, can you load a bundled JS file dynamically at runtime.